# How to display php mysql select value in popup

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, ajax

i want to pass mysql select value (UID) to css popup.this is my code what I have tried.but it's display empty textbox.this pop up button display when click on delete button.i want to pass relavent user UID to popup.

```
    <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User ID</th>
                                <th>Facebook ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>E-mail</th>
                                <th></th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>  
                          <?php

                        $query = 'SELECT * FROM Users ';
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {   

                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row['UID'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td  class="center">'.$row['Fuid'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="center">'.$row['Ffname'].'</td>';
                echo '<td  class="center">'.$row['Femail'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.'<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-setting" >'.'Delete'.'</a>'.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';   
                }                           
                ?>
                </tr>
                 </tbody>
                  </table>

 <form action="db_sql/db_delete_supplier.php" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1" >
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h3>Delete Supplier</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Are you sure to delete this supplier from system ...? </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="text" name="UID" value="<?php echo $row['UID'];?>" />
                        <!--<a href="user.php" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="no">Close</a>
                        <a href="db_sql/db_delete_supplier.php" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" name="yes">Delete</a>-->
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="no" value="Close" />
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="yes"  value="Delete"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image: Users Table]

Comment: How is the `popup.html` being rendered? Please provide your file structure

Comment: @CodeGodie sorry it's not popup.html ,it's html code for popup.both php and popup codes in same page

Comment: Do you see a 500 error in the browser - if, yes, what does it say? Check using the Chrome Inspector (or a similar tool)

Comment: @TJ- no not any error.

Comment: Hold on, the popup code with `$row['UID']` is not within  the loop - correct? How would it have access to that variable?

Comment: @TJ- i'v put it ($row['UID']) insight in to while loop.but same result.empty textbox

Comment: Please post the updated code. Also, please double check that `UID` is the desired column in the table.

Comment: hey again.. it seems to me that you need to explain your code better.. you have php code on top of your page thats looping through the db results rendering table elements, to some table (that you havent shown)... then the form is trying to use that `$row['uid']` which you have not declared since its inside the loop.. how do you not get errors?... what are you trying to accomplish in your table?

Comment: I have upload my full code within mysql table.please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"popup.php?cat_id=".$row["cat_id"]." \">Edit</a>"; ?>
```

Put this code in While loop , so this will open pop-up windows with query-string of cat-id.

Now from that ID you can fetch all records in pop-up.

This is possible solution you can do....

Note : you can pass any ID which is unique so that you can execute select query on pop-up page and it will fetch data from database